# Convert AI and EPS files to use in HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, canvas

I have a product customizer. Right now it allows JPG and PNG to be uploaded. Our clients often have AI or EPS files. Is there an easy way to convert the AI or EPS files so they can be used in a Canvas? The hope would be to do it through jquery but C# wouldnt be the end of the world. I can use Base64 as well.

Comment: In browser there is currently no readily available solution to convert AI/EPS (or PS). On server side you can use [ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/) (GNU Affero license), which also do PDF btw..

Comment: Thanks... I'll have a look into that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is super old but we ended up using Cloud Convert API as a solution. Send in the AI, EPS or PDF and you get back a png...It doesn't do it directly client side but it does do it on the fly on the web.